# Getting Out of Bounds Exception when trying to use Recursion for Fibonacci Sequence(JAVA)

Tags: recursion, indexoutofboundsexception

I would also appreciate it if somebody were to explain to me the solution to this problem because I think my logic is incorrect.

```
public class FibanacciSequence {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        fibSeq(5,5);        
    }
    
    public static int[] fibSeq(int startNum, int iterations) 
    {
        int[] arr = new int[iterations];
        int nextNum = 0;
        arr[0] = startNum;
        
        if(iterations == 0) 
        {
            return arr;         
        }       
        else 
        {
            arr[nextNum] = startNum+startNum;
            arr[nextNum+1] = nextNum + startNum;
            arr=fibSeq(nextNum,iterations-1);       
        }       
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Imagine what happens when you call `fibSeq(0, 1)` (which at some point will happen, regardless of your inital parameters) You create an array of size `1` but try to access indexes `0`and `1`. An array of size 1 does not have an index `1`. And also image, what happens if you reach at the point where `iterations == 0`. You create an array of size `0` and try to set the value at index `0`, which obviously cannot exist in an array of size 0

Comment: For the general help with the issues of the problem, you should first explain, what you are trying to do ...

Comment: This is the perfect time to learn to use the debugger to step through the code. You can watch the value of variables and see where you have a logic error that allows you to run off the end of the array.

Comment: Furthermore, you are adding values to some array, but then replacing the complete array with result of your recusive call., so letting all the out of bounds exceptions aside, your result will always be an empty array

Answer (score 0):

When iterations <= 0, your code will fail on the line

```
arr[0] = startNum;
```

When 0 < iterations <= nextNum + 1, your code will fail on the lines

```
arr[nextNum] = startNum + startNum;
arr[nextNum + 1] = nextNum + startNum;
```

You should probably work out your plan in more detail on paper before coding.